# apex repeat with pagination

Tags: visualforce

I am a new developer and need some help with pagination and the apex:repeat function.

Here is my controller trimmed down to just the needed bits.

**EDIT: Here is my complete controller**

```
public class TrophyCaseController {

    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }
    public WorkSummary[] WorkSummaries { get; set; }

    // The line below was added to your provided example
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController BCS_SSC {get;private set;}

    private String sortField = 'Performance_Points_YTD__c';
    private String sortDirection = 'DESC';
    string userIdStr = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('UserID');


    //Leaderboard Pages
    //
    //Get the top 3 BCSs
    public List<BCS__c> getLeaders() {

        List<BCS__c> results = Database.query(
            'SELECT Id, Name, Performance_Points_MTD__c, Performance_Points_YTD__c, User__r.FullPhotoURL, User__r.Id ' +
            'FROM BCS__c ' +
            'ORDER BY ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDirection + ' LIMIT 3'
        );
        return results;
    }

        // Also adding a constructor
    public TrophyCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        List<BCS__c> leaders = getLeaders();
        BCS_SSC = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, Name, Performance_Points_MTD__c, Performance_Points_YTD__c, User__r.FullPhotoURL ' +
            'FROM BCS__c ' +
            'WHERE Id NOT IN :leaders ' +
            'ORDER BY ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDirection
        ));
        BCS_SSC.setPageSize(15);
    }

    //Get all the other BCSs exluding the three above
    public List<BCS__c> getAllBCS() {

        /*List<BCS__c> results = Database.query(
            'SELECT Id, Name, Performance_Points_MTD__c, Performance_Points_YTD__c, User__r.FullPhotoURL ' +
            'FROM BCS__c ' +
            'ORDER BY ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDirection + ' LIMIT 15 OFFSET 3'
        );
        return results;*/

        List<BCS__c> results = BCS_SSC.getRecords();
        return results;

    }

    //User Detail Pages
    //
    public TrophyCaseController() {
        //Get performance badges for individual user
        AggregateResult[] results = [
            SELECT Performance_Badge__c, MAX(Badge_Image__c) badgeURL, COUNT(Name) badgeCount FROM Performance_Metric__c WHERE User__c = :userIdStr GROUP BY Performance_Badge__c
        ];
        Summaries = new List<Summary>();
        for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
            Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
        }

        //Get work.com badges aka Culture badges
        AggregateResult[] workresults = [
            SELECT Count(Id) workCount, DefinitionID, MAX(Definition.Name) workName, MAX(ImageURL) workImage FROM WorkBadge WHERE RecipientID = :userIdStr GROUP BY DefinitionID
        ];
        WorkSummaries = new List<WorkSummary>();

        for (AggregateResult ar : workresults) {
            WorkSummaries.add(new WorkSummary(ar));
        }

    }

    //LIst of performance badges
    public class Summary {
        public Integer BadgeCount { get; private set; }
        public String Badge { get; private set; }
        public String BadgeURL { get; private set; }

        public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
            badgeCount = (Integer) ar.get('badgeCount');
            BadgeURL = (String) ar.get('badgeURL');
            Badge = (String) ar.get('Performance_Badge__c');
        }
    }

    //List of work.com badges
    public class WorkSummary {
        public Integer workCount { get; private set; }
        public String DefinitionID { get; private set; }
        public String workName { get; private set; }
        public String workImage { get; private set; }

        public WorkSummary(AggregateResult ar) {
            workCount = (Integer) ar.get('workCount');
            DefinitionID = (String) ar.get('DefinitionID');
            workName = (String) ar.get('workName');
            workImage = (String) ar.get('workImage');
        }
    }

    public User getUser() {
        List<User> results = [
            select FirstName,
            LastName,
            FullPhotoURL,
            Performance_Points_MTD_User__c,
            Performance_Points_YTD_User__c
            from User
            where Id = :userIdStr
        ];

        if (!results.isEmpty()) {
            return results.get(0);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

**Edit: Here is my complete VF page:**

```
<apex:page controller="TrophyCaseController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">

    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .header {
                width:100%;
                float:center;
                margin: auto auto;
                background-color:lightblue;
                color:black;
                font-size:150%;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight: bold;
                clear: both;
                }
                .leaders {
                float:center;
                margin: auto auto;
                font-size:150%;
                text-align:center;
                align-items:center;
                clear:both;
                }
                .everyone {
                float:center;
                margin: auto auto;
                width: auto;
                font-size:100%;
                text-align:center;
                clear:both;
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>

            <br/>

            <div class="leaders">

                <apex:repeat value="{!Leaders}" var="B"> 
                    <apex:outputPanel style="float:left;width:33%;text-align:center;">
                        <apex:panelgrid >
                            <apex:panelGroup >
                                <apex:outputText value="{!Floor(B.Performance_Points_YTD__c)}" style="font-weight: bold;margin:110px;"/><br/><br/>  
                                <apex:outputLink value="/apex/TrophyCase_User_V3" id="theLink" style="">
                                    <apex:param name="UserID" value="{!B.User__r.Id}" />
                                    <apex:image url="{!B.User__r.FullPhotoURL}" style="border-radius:50%;" width="150px" height="150px"/><br/>
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!B.Name}" style=""/><br/>
                                </apex:outputLink>
                            </apex:panelGroup>
                        </apex:panelgrid>
                    </apex:outputPanel> 
                </apex:repeat>
            </div>

            <div class="everyone">
                <apex:form>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align:center;">
                        <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasPrevious}" value="First" action="{!BCS_SSC.first}" />
                        <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasPrevious}" value="Prev" action="{!BCS_SSC.previous}" />
                        <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasNext}" value="Next" action="{!BCS_SSC.next}" />
                        <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasNext}" value="Last" action="{!BCS_SSC.last}" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                    <apex:repeat value="{!AllBCS}" var="B"> 
                        <apex:outputPanel >

                            <apex:panelgrid style="float:left;width:20%;">
                                <apex:panelGroup >
                                    <br/>
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!Floor(B.Performance_Points_YTD__c)}" style="font-weight: bold;"/><br/>  
                                    <apex:outputLink value="/apex/TrophyCase_User_V3" id="theLink">
                                        <apex:param name="UserID" value="{!B.User__r.Id}" />
                                        <apex:image url="{!B.User__r.FullPhotoURL}" style="border-radius: 50%" width="75px" height="75px"/><br/>
                                        <apex:outputText value="{!B.Name}"/><br/>
                                    </apex:outputLink>

                                </apex:panelGroup>
                            </apex:panelgrid>
                        </apex:outputPanel> 
                    </apex:repeat>
                </apex:form>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Right now I have the query locked to 15 records but I want to create a page system to show 15 records of the possible 150 or so records.

How should I go about this?

Here is an example of my current page. The top three records are from a different query so I am only concerned with the lower records on the page. 
[image]

Comment: what is the problem here. As per snapshot you are able to show all 15 members. What you want to achieve. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you're looking for is pretty handily provided by `ApexPages.StandardSetController`

In your controller, you'd pass it a query locator, set a page size, and that's pretty much it! The pagination methods (`first`, `last`, `next`, and `prev`) are provided by the standardSetController.

I'm adapting this from some code that I've written from my org (I use a `apex:pageBlockTable` instead of `apex:repeat`). Hopefully, everything will still work. Modifying your provided code results in this

```
public class TrophyCaseController {
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }
    public WorkSummary[] WorkSummaries { get; set; }

    // The line below was added to your provided example
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController BCS_SSC {get;private set;}

    private String sortField = 'Performance_Points_YTD__c';
    private String sortDirection = 'DESC';
    string userIdStr = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('UserID');

    // Also adding a constructor
    public TrophyCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        BCS_SSC = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, Name, Performance_Points_MTD__c, Performance_Points_YTD__c, User__r.FullPhotoURL ' +
            'FROM BCS__c ' +
            'ORDER BY ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDirection + ' OFFSET 3'
        ));
        BCS_SSC.setPageSize(15);
    }

    public List<BCS__c> getAllBCS() {
        // The line below was modified
        List<BCS__c> results = BCS_SSC.getRecords();
        return results;
    }
}
```

**+edit:** Realized that the query locator needed to be created outside of the method in which it is used for this to work

**+edit2:** Upon further investigation, it appears that `ApexPages.StandardSetController` can't handle the `OFFSET` clause in the query locator. One way to work around this limitation would be to store your 'leaders' in a list, and replace the `OFFSET 3` clause with a `WHERE Id NOT IN :leaders` clause.

It's probably a better idea to run your BCS leaders query once, and store the result in a class attribute...but in the interest of getting this working, the constructor should now look like this

```
public TrophyCaseController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
    List<BCS__c> leaders = getLeaders();
    BCS_SSC = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
        'SELECT Id, Name, Performance_Points_MTD__c, Performance_Points_YTD__c, User__r.FullPhotoURL ' +
        'FROM BCS__c ' +
        'WHERE Id NOT IN :leaders ' +
        'ORDER BY ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDirection
    ));
    BCS_SSC.setPageSize(15);
}
```

**/edit2**

I believe that you don't even need to change your `<apex:repeat>` section in your visualforce page to get this working up to this point.

Adding the pagination controls should be as simple as stuffing the following snippet somewhere in your Visualforce page

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align:center;">
    <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasPrevious}" value="First" action="{!BCS_SSC.first}" />
    <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasPrevious}" value="Prev" action="{!BCS_SSC.previous}" />
    <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasNext}" value="Next" action="{!BCS_SSC.next}" />
    <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!BCS_SSC.hasNext}" value="Last" action="{!BCS_SSC.last}" />
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Things to note when making use of this pagination method:

- The StandardSetController may keep an open query cursor. I don't know of a good way to test this, but you're only allowed 10 open query cursors ([Relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query_querylocator.htm))
- This will only work for sObjects (both Standard objects, and Custom objects)

Comment: Thanks Derek, I will let you know once i have a chance to test your suggested code and I will then mark your response as the answer.

Comment: That didn't work. The controls show up but they are all disabled.

Comment: I have updated my original question with my complete visual force page. FYI, as I said I am new to VisualForce and before this I had only done very basic HTML so I know some of my code is ugly but it works.

Comment: Did you update your controller as well as your visualforce page? Just to be sure, you do currently have more than 15 records in your BSC__c object, right? Perhaps this is an issue with the `OFFSET 3` part of the query, try removing it and see if it works.

Comment: I have updated the original post again and included my complete controller and VF page.

Comment: I don't understand how the list that you are creating is being called on my visualforce page. Shouldn't I need to change the apex:repeat to look at the list you are creating?

Comment: It should work fine if you update your `getAllBCS()` method to what I provided. The `{!AllBCS}` in your `apex:repeat` is calling your `getAllBCS()` method. Right now, you're still running your original query in `getAllBCS()`. Changing that method to return the records from `BCS_SSC` instead of running your current query should work.

Comment: ahhhhh! I was trying to figure out if you wanted me to swap that in for my code or not.

Comment: Uggggh, now I am getting a "Attempt to de-reference a null object" error on the VF page. Original question controller code has been updated to current version. I commented out my query and put your query in its place under getallbcs()

Comment: Which line in your controller are you getting that error? As line numbers aren't displayed here, something of the form "In method <x>, the line starting with <y>" would be helpful.